# Complex multiplication as rotation

Tags: complex-numbers, rotations

Is there a reason that complex numbers multiplied so readily represent rotations in a plane?  Any intuition behind this would help.

Comment: The fundamental connection between these is the formula $$e^{ix}=\cos x + i \sin x.$$ I suggest you to read "Visual Complex Analysis" by Tristan Needham for more information.

Comment: If you are not familiar with $e^{ix}$, you may consider the following  (equivalent) explanation.

Comment: Any complex numbers $a$ and $b$ can be written as 
$$ a=|a|(\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha) $$
and
$$ b=|b|(\cos \beta + i\sin \beta) $$ 
Using the rules of complex multiplication we get 
$$ ab=|a||b|((\cos \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \alpha \sin \beta) + i(\cos \alpha \sin \beta + \cos \beta \sin \alpha)) $$
But, we know that
$$ \cos \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \alpha \sin \beta = \cos (\alpha +\beta)$$
$$ \cos \alpha \sin \beta + \cos \beta \sin \alpha = \sin(\alpha + \beta)$$
So 
$$ ab=|a||b|((\cos (\alpha + \beta) + i \sin( \alpha + \beta)) $$
And you see that adding angles means rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you extend the field $\mathbb{R}$ by adjoining a root $\alpha$ of the equation:
$$
x^2 + 1 = 0
$$
the extension field $\mathbb{R}(\alpha)$ properly contains $\mathbb{R}$ since an ordered field lacks square roots of elements less than zero.

$\mathbb{R}(\alpha)$ is a 2-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and we may take as a basis the pair $\{1,\alpha\}$. with respect to this basis this basis, multiplication by an element $c+\alpha d$ can be viewed as a linear transformation, with the matrix representation:
$$
a+\alpha b \to \begin{pmatrix} a &-b \\ b &a \end{pmatrix}
$$
the determinant  $D=a^2+b^2$ is positive unless $a=b=0$. so we can find $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ satisfying:
$$
\cos \theta = aD^{-\frac12} \\
\sin \theta = bD^{-\frac12} 
$$
and the multiplication factorizes into a real multiplication coupled with an anticlockwise rotation through $\theta$

Answer (score 4):

You can represent the complex number $z=x+iy$ by $z=re^{i\theta}$, where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta$ is the counter-clockwise angle from the positive $x$ axis. So if we multiply two complex numbers together, e.g. $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $w=se^{i\phi}$ we get
$$zw = re^{i\theta}se^{i\phi}=(rs)e^{i(\theta+\phi)},$$
so as you can see the resulting complex number has angle $\theta+\phi$ and length $rs$.